# Does Java GC destroy objects if instance variables still have reference?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I've read through some of the Java garbage collection guides online, but I'm still a bit unclear and wanted to make sure so that I don't have memory leaks in my code.

Does Java GC collect objects that lost its reference, but its variables still have reference?

So let's say I have SomeObject:

```
public class SomeObject {
    public ObjectVar var;

    public SomeObject() {
        var = new ObjectVar();
    }
}
```

And my code:

```
SomeObject obj1 = new SomeObject();
SomeObject obj2 = new SomeObject();
obj2.var = obj1.var;
obj1 = null;
```

So obj1's var has reference, but obj1 no longer has any reference. So, will the GC destroy obj1, but keep var alive? (I'm assuming so; just wanted to make sure). Thanks!

Comment: The basic rule for GC is that if GC'ing an object would affect your program, it doesn't happen.  (Unless you're using the specialized tools that care about GC, but if you're using that, you'll know.)

Comment: You might want to read about ["Midlife Crisis"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2003/12/04/41281.aspx).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is what is going to happen (see comments below)

```
// obj1 and obj1.var get created
SomeObject obj1 = new SomeObject();
// obj2 and obj2.var get created
SomeObject obj2 = new SomeObject();
// old obj2.var becomes eligible for GC
obj2.var = obj1.var;
// obj1 becomes eligible for GC
obj1 = null;
```

In the end, two objects remain that do not get GCd - `obj2` and the former `obj1.var` which is now referenced as `obj2.var`.

Note: In a special case of `ObjectVar` class being a non-static inner class of `SomeObject`, keeping a reference to `obj1.var` would also keep `obj1` around. This is because internally the `SomeObject.ObjectVar` class has a hidden variable of type `SomeObject`, which references the outer object of the inner class.

Comment: Ok thanks! But now I'm confused because two people have different answers. If ObjectVar was a subclass (or inner class) of SomeObject, the above code will make obj1 ineligible for GC?

Comment: @baekacaek ZyyaoWei's comment considered only static inner classes, in which case it does not matter indeed. Non-static inner classes and anonymous or named method-local classes can keep the host object from being garbage collected, but static inner classes cannot.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification, and quick replies!

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course.

Remember, what you store in the `var` field is actually reference to the object, not the object itself. So when GC collects `obj1`, the `var` object is untouched (**must not be touched**), especially since it has a reference from `obj2`, which is still alive and well..

Comment: Thanks, does the same apply if ObjectVar is an inner class of SomeObject?

Comment: Well that should not matter, since no matter what obj2 has a reference to that object.

Comment: If it's a static inner class, it doesn't matter indeed. However, when it's a non-static inner class, `var` has a "back reference" to the outer class, which may keep the owner alive for longer than one would expect.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks, did not though about that old object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the behaviour is as you describe. The general rule for garbage collection is that objects only become eligible when you cannot reach them through any hard reference. Any objects you can reach this way will thus never be garbage collected (with the exception of soft / weak references.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, if an object is still reachable by a path of references, it is guaranteed to survive collection. If there is no such path, the object can no longer be accessed, and may safely be collected.

After the first two lines, the memory looks like this:

```
o1  --> SomeObj#1 --> ObjectVar#1
o2  --> SomeObj#2 --> ObjectVar#2
```

All 4 objects can be reached, if a garbage collection were to occur at this time, none of them would be collected.

After the 3rd line, it looks like this:

```
o1  --> SomeObj#1 --> ObjectVar#1
                      ^
o2  --> SomeObj#2 -----    ObjectVar#2
```

Now, only 3 objects can be reached; the garbage collector may remove ObjectVar#2.

After the 4th line, it looks like this:

```
o1      SomeObj#1 --> ObjectVar#1
                      ^
o2  --> SomeObj#2 -----   ObjectVar#2
```

Only two objects are still reachable; the garbage collector may remove SomeObj#1 and ObjectVar#2, but must keep SomeObj#2 and ObjectVar#1.